# Bash Look for String at Position X After String is Matched in File

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to add some div containers to an html file. I figure there are two sets of logic.
**First** is to look for a string at position X, then insert `<div ...>` at the end of the line. I have this working.
**Second** set of logic is to look for string at position X after the above condition is satisfied, then insert the container closure `</div>`.

At the moment I can look for the `button` string at position 2 and insert `<div ...>`, I'm using a while loop for this. If you have any ideas on how to tackle the second bit of logic that'd be much appreciated.

**Here is a snippet of the html file:**

```
...
<p>test.txt</p>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">tmp</button>
    <p>example1.txt</p>
    <p>example2.txt</p>
    <p>example3.txt</p>
<p>example.txt</p>
...
```

**The end result I need is:**

```
...
<p>test.txt</p>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">tmp</button>
<div>
    <p>example1.txt</p>
    <p>example2.txt</p>
    <p>example3.txt</p>
</div>
<p>example.txt</p>
...
```

Comment: Attempting to edit HTML in a Bash script seems wrong on so many levels.

Comment: @tripleee Any suggestions on how you would do it then?

Comment: Depending on what "it" means here, perhaps generate the HTML from a template if you need to stay in Bash; or create a style sheet which hides the unwanted element in some circumstances.

Comment: @tripleee the HTML is originally generated via the `tree` command with the -H flag. So I don't have much control over the generation of the originating data unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution but it isn't pretty

```
#!/bin/bash
  
count=0
openlinesfound=(0)
closelinesfound=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
     ((count+=1))
     # If word button is found at position 12 of the line
     if [[ $(echo ${line:12:6}) = "button" ]] ; then
         openlinesfound+=("$count")
         actioned=0
         echo -e "$line\n<div class=\"content\">"
     else
         # If <p> is found at position 11 of the line
         if [[ $(echo ${line:11:3}) = "<p>" ]] ; then
             closelinesfound+=("$count")
             # If <p> has been found after the last button has been found
             if [[ "${closelinesfound[-1]}" -gt "${openlinesfound[-1]}" ]] ; then
                     # This is to prevent it from running on every <p> after the button
                     if [[ $actioned -eq 0 ]] ; then
                         echo -e "</div>\n$line"
                         actioned=1
                     else
                         echo $line
                     fi
             else
                 echo $line
             fi
         else
             echo $line
         fi
     fi
done < test.html
```

Comment: Indeed, Awk would probably be prettier and more succinct, as well as faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this far now but it's still not perfect and misses a few.
I'd be curious if anyone else has a better solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=test.html

buttonline=($(awk 's=index($0, "<button") { print NR }' $infile))
buttonpos=($(awk 's=index($0, "<button") { print s }' $infile))
itemline=($(awk 's=index($0, "<p") { print NR }' $infile))
itempos=($(awk 's=index($0, "<p") { print s }' $infile))


j=0
k=0
divopenline=()
divcloseline=()
for ((i=0; i<${#buttonline[@]} || i<${#itemline[@]}; i++))
do
  if (( ${buttonline[i-k]:-0} > ${itemline[i+j]:-0} )); then
    ((j+=1))
    ((k+=1))
  elif (( ${buttonline[i-k]:-0} < ${itemline[i+j]:-0} )); then
    for ((l=0; l<${#buttonpos[@]} || l<${#itempos[@]}; l++))
    do
        if [[ ${buttonpos[i-k]:-0} -ge ${itempos[i+j+l]:-0} ]]; then
            divopenline+=(${buttonline[i-k]})
        divcloseline+=(${itemline[i+j+l]})
        l=0
        break
        fi
    done
  fi
done



count=1
for i in ${divopenline[@]}
do
    j=$(expr $i + $count)
    sed -i "$j i <div class=\"content\">" $infile
    ((count+=1))
done

count=1
for i in ${divcloseline[@]}
do
    j=$(expr $i + $count)
    sed -i "$j i <\/div>" $infile
    ((count+=2))
done
```